# SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org fails with error unexpected token '»'

Tags: apex

About the trailhead module "[Find and Fix Bugs with Apex Replay Debugger > Debug Your Code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger/apex-replay-debugger-debug-your-code?trailmix_creator_id=fragon&trailmix_slug=visual-studio-code)".

After toggling the checkpoint in vscode, I tried to update the checkpoint in the connected org, but it fails:

Steps to reproduce:

- Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift +P)
- SFDX: Toggle Checkpoint
- Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift +P)
- SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org

Apex Replay Debugger Output:

- Starting SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org
- SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org, Step 1 of 6: Retrieving org information
- Ending SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org

Visual Studio Code also returns a prompt with the error:

[image]

Path to the folder doesn't have spaces or  some type of special characters.

Did anyone experienced the same error?

Thanks in advance.